# Java swing save several text field to a object

Tags: java, swing

Im quite new to java swing but im creating a stock management program, i have now my window registration form were the user can insert, name, adress, username, password, etc, and i have a button below to save all data.
I want to e able to press the save button and all the data be saved to a new userObject, my problem is how to associate each textfield data so they can be saved to new object in save button.
Can anyone give me some pointers on how to do this?

Thanks!

I tried the code this way:

private void ButtonSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
   User obj=new User();
   String userName = UserTextFieldName.getText();
   String userAdress = UserTextFieldAdress.getText();
   String userCitizenID = UserTextFieldCitizenID.getInteger();
   obj.setName(userName);
   obj.setAdress(userAdress);
   obj.setCitizenID(userCitizenID);

   usersArrayList.add(obj);
```

//this is were i would give a save correctly message and dispose the registration window.

Is this a good alternative method?i could not make it working the other way with the ActionListener...

Comment: Create a class called UserObject, make ``String`` members for each text field you want to save and then assign the text fields's values to these members either using setters or in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i already have a userObject class, and the setters/constructor, still i dont know how to assign all the textfield data to the save button so it can save a new userObject...

Comment: register your save button to `ActionListener` and handle button click event by implementing `actionPerformed()`. In `actionPerformed()` you can grab values from `textfields` and assign it to the attributes of your `UserObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add an ActonListener to your button.

Something like:

```
JButton save = new JButton( "Save" );
save.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    }
        UserObject user = new UserObject();
        user.setName( nameTextField.getText() );
        user.setAddress( addressTextField.getText() );
        ...
    }
});
```

Read the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for Swing basics.

There are sections on:

1. `How to Use Buttons`
2. `How to Write an ActionListener`

that each contain working examples to get your started.

Comment: This kind of worked i managed to do it without the ActionListener, but im now having the problem of variables in the text fields that are not strings, i cannot getText from them, is there another way to get the values?

Comment: @Dan Of course you need the ActionListener is you want the data in the text field at the time the "Save" button is clicked. All data in a text field is a String so I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Yes all data in the textfield is a string but i have for example telephone number wich is a int, i already solved it and declared the phone number as a String.